# WordPress 2MB memory limit coming from nowhere

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, virtualhost

I have just downloaded a fresh new WordPress to a virtual server where a WP and MediaWiki are already running smoothly. The memory_limit in php.ini is set to 256MB. But for some reason WP thinks it is limited to only 2MB, see Apache log entry below.

```
[Sun Nov 19 08:50:21.692866 2017] [:error] [pid 74814] [client 109.81.213.117:59968]
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
131072 bytes) in /var/www/foo.bar/subdomain/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 452
```

When I print phpinfo() from the index.php file of my new WP, it shows the 256MB limit so there is no second secret php.ini configuration for this subdomain or directory.

I also tried to find a mischievous setting of memory limit in .htaccess or php file but with no avail. (`grep -r "memory_limit" .`)

Any ideas where this 2MB limit could be coming from?

**UPDATE**

I put `ini_get('memory_limit'); exit;` in the middle of wp-settings.php where it is including other files. Sometimes it writes the `256MB` as it is supposed to, sometimes it dies in `/var/www/iurium.cz/daily/wp-includes/wp-db.php` with the error of 2MB. The behavior is quite random.

What else can influence the memory limit if not htaccess, php.ini or ini_set? Does it have to do with PHP at all? Can it be set in the system somehow?

Comment: Do phpinfo() right before line 452 (if that's where it happens regularly) as well as an ini_get(). Also, if you've updated the ini file and use php-fpm or something similar, the ini file may not have been re-read by the process handling that request (the `pid` number should be the same for your phpinfo()-call). Also remember that phpinfo shows two values, one global and one local.

Comment: .htaccess file or wp-config.php?

Comment: You ever get this figured out?

Comment: @ClaytonLeis no solution, we scratched the project...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your `memory_limit` value is `256M` (not `256MB`).

The PHP description of resource limits calls for `256M` https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

You can use `phpinfo()` or `ini_get('memory_limit')` to check the value.

If `memory_limit` doesn't match the expected format, PHP will default to `2M` (`2097152` bytes)

Comment: I like your suggestion, unfortunately I can not validate it since the project was scratched. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I was having the same problem ... 128MB instead of 128M

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem. No idea what's causing it. Alleviated it by using `@ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`
in wp-config.php

Some plugin (or theme file) is changing memory_limit somewhere.